# How i can increase size of legends in line Highchart

Tags: highcharts

How i can increase legend symbol size, I have tried these properties
`symbolHeight: 12`
`symbolWidth: 12`
`symbolRadius: 6` but these are not working for line chart.

code:https://jsfiddle.net/juvcfkmh/4/

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Round legend symbols'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr']
    },

    legend: {
        symbolHeight: 12,
        symbolWidth: 12,
        symbolRadius: 6
    },

    series: [{
        data: [1, 3, 2, 4]
    }, {
        data: [6, 4, 5, 3]
    }, {
        data: [2, 7, 6, 5]
    }]

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The legend appearance is based on a series marker, so you can for example create another series without data, define marker options and link the real series.

```
    series: [{
        ...,
        id: 'firstSeries',
        marker: {
            radius: 15
        },
        data: []
    }, {
        ...,
        linkedTo: 'firstSeries',
        data: [...]
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4yrk5dq1/